# HaProxy path regex not working as expected

Tags: regex, acl, haproxy

With the following urls I need to use backend A

```
/yyy/some-name/zzz/some-other-name
/yyy/some-name/zzz/some-other-name/1
/yyy/some-name/zzz/some-other-name/2
/yyy/some-name/zzz/some-other-name/3
/yyy/some-name/zzz/some-other-name/4
```

and with these urls backend B

```
/old/yyy/some-name/zzz/some-other-name
    /yyy/some-name/zzz/some-other-name/1?param=test
    /yyy/some-name/zzz/some-other-name/2?param=test
```

I'm using the following rules

```
acl rule_a path_reg -i ^\/yyy\/.+\/zzz\/([a-z]|-|[0-9])*($|\/[1-4])$
use_backend backend_a if rule_a

default_backend backend_b
```

[You can try out the regex here](https://regex101.com/r/b85yzv/4/)

The problem is, **all** the urls mentionned above are going to backend A, but I expected the ones containing query params to go to backend B.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need a `url_reg` instead. Try it like this (I've simplified the pattern a bit)

```
acl rule_a url_reg -i ^\/yyy\/.+\/zzz\/([a-z0-9-])+($|\/[1-4]$)
use_backend backend_a if rule_a
```

Comment: Thanks :) will try it out tomorrow. What's the difference between url_reg and path_reg ? Why is my rule not working ?

Comment: Thanks it's working! I understood my mistake, path does not contain the query params.

Comment: Sorry, I was pretty busy yesterday and could not respond in time. I am glad it worked. Yes, there is also `urlp_reg` that can be used for this purpose.